# Multiple level template inheritance in Jinja2?

Tags: python, css, django, django-templates, jinja2

I do html/css by trade, and I have been working on and off django projects as a template designer. I'm currently working on a site that uses Jinja2, which I have been using for about 2 weeks. I just found out through reading the documentation that Jinja2 doesn't support multiple level template inheritance, as in you can't do more than one

```
{% extends "foo" %}
```

per rendering. Now I'm pretty sure you can do this in Django, which is powerful because you can specify a base template, specify 3 or 4 templates based on that, and then build the meat of your pages using those base templates. Isn't the point of inheritance so you have more power to abstract so your only really messing with unique code?

In any case I have no idea what to do here. I don't know if there is some way I can do it that will work as well as it could with the Django templates. I'm not exactly an expert at either Django or Jinja(2) but I can provide any information needed.

Comment: Please provide the link that says Jinja2 can't do multiple levels of inheritance.  Have you tried to have a template hierarchy?  What errors did you get?

Comment: http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/documentation/templates#extends
- "There is no support for multiple inheritance."

Comment: @xckpd7: Multiple inheritance is not the same thing as multiple levels of single inheritance. I see no support for multiple inheritance in Django, either.   Please provide some examples to clarify whether you're talking about multiple levels of inheritance or actual multiple inheritance.

Comment: @S.Lott: all I want to be able to do, is have a base template, have 3 or 4 base templates based on that, and be able to create templates based on those, to provide ultimate flexibility. I was under the impression that you did this by specifying an extends on the sub base templates, and on the individual html templates, which would could as 2 or more {% extends %} tags and therefore violates the part of the documentation that says you can only use one {% extends %} per render. I maybe right, or wrong, but given what I have asked, is there anyway to do this?

Comment: @xckpd7: Please do not write extended comments on your own question.  Please update the question.  Please provide an example of what you think you want to do.  Please provide the problem you're actually having.  You can have a hierarchy of templates of any depth, so I don't understand what's not working with the solution you're currently trying to make work.  Please update the question with sample code.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The way the documentation worded it, it seemed like it didn't support inheritance (n) levels deep.

> Unlike Python Jinja does not support
>   multiple inheritance. So you can only
>   have one extends tag called per
>   rendering.

I didn't know it was just a rule saying 1 extends per template.... I now know, with some help from the jinja irc channel.

Comment: I'm glad to see you sorted this out, I was wondering the same thing. I thought your original question was fairly clear. It can be so annoying to deal with the egos on StackOverflow -- someone above must have been very cranky the day you asked this question.

Comment: For what it's worth, i just deployed multi-level extending with jinja2 with perfect success, thanks to this post so i have a base.html, then extend it with further base_admin.html, base_client.html, base_form.html, etc. and then finally extend them with the actual pages, like accounts.html. No more code duplication!

Answer (score 43):

One of the best way to achieve multiple level of templating using jinja2 is to use 'include'
let say you have '**base_layout.html**' as your base template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Base Layout</title>
<div>
  <h1>Base</h1>
  .... // write your code here
  {% block body %}{% endblock %}
</div>
```

and then you want to have '**child_layout.html**' that extends 'base_layout.

```
{% include "base_layout.html" %}
  <div>
  ... // write your code here
  </div>
{% block body %}{% endblock %}
```

and now your page can just extends '**child_layout.html**' and it will have both **base_layout.html** and **child_layout.html**

```
{% extends "child_layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
  ...// write your code here
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: if I am not mistaken the problem of include is that it loads the html file even if there is no necessity for that file or even if the user did not make a request. But the advantage of extends is that the html file is rendered upon request. which will save time for loading the full page especially when there are lots of html files with huge codes

Answer (score 17):

Try this, this work for me thanks to @Ixm answer.

**base.html**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <body>
      {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

**content.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<table>
  <tr>
  {% include "footer.html" %}
  </tr>
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

**footer.html**

```
{% block footer %} <td> test</td>{% endblock %}
```

and call with

```
env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader(os.path.join(path, "Layouts")))
template = env.get_template('content.html')
html = template.render()
print html
```

Comment: this question still has a lot of life left in it, even 5 years later! Pretty funny.

Comment: Why do you need the block on the footer if its being included?

Comment: @Rey - Let’s make that 11 years later!  Nice one.

Comment: I noticed that an included file cannot replace blocks. It seems it is included after extending? I would have preferred that includes are executed first, such that `footer.html` could replace blocks from `base.html`, but it seems to be impossible.

Answer (score 12):

After struggling for a long time, I found `{{super}}` for multiple levels of inheritance in jinja2 templates.

The following is inspired from https://stackoverflow.com/a/31093830/1300775.

`base.html`

```
<html>
<body>
  {% block title %}
    Brand
  {% endblock %}
</body>
```

`layer-1.html`

```
  {% extends "base.html" %}
  {% block title %}
    {{ super() }} - Section
  {% endblock %}
```

`layer-2.html`

```
  {% extends "layer-1.html" %}
  {% block title %}
    {{ super() }} - Article
  {% endblock %}
```

Rendering template `layer-2.html` will output `Brand - Section - Article` in block `title`.

Comment: dunno why someone gave you -1 but this was what I was looking for to embed my app inside an existing dashboard layout

Comment: @mLstudent33, if an answer is what you are looking for go ahead and up-vote it (click the triangle above the score).

Comment: Works perfectly! Fullfilled my requirements and saved a lot of time.

Answer (score 4):

I recently faced the same issue. I wanted to inherit several child templates and it worked. To illustrate it I would like to show you a solution that worked for me:

I had a base.html file that has block content and extended by manage.html. and that manage.html has a block sub_manage which is extended by internet_market.html, so visually it looks like:

```
|- base.html (block content)
|--manage.html (extends base.html)
|---sub_manage.html (extends manage.html)
```

when I rendered it, everythink worked fine, which means that you can have several {% extends %} in one render. the only thing is that if you are using relative links to your css or js files then it might not work, rather it will render, but it won't find your css/js files. 
like:

```
<head>  
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
</head>
```

In that case you have to use dynamic links by using url_for. like:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url_for("static", filename = "css/bootstrap.min.css")}}">
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{url_for("static", filename = "js/bootstrap.min.js")}}"></script>
<style type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 3):

See the documentation [extending](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#extend), [including](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#include), and [importing](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#import).

This provides the means of getting functionality from multiple files for different purposes and is different from the depth of the nesting.
You can perfectly have a template that extends a template that extends a template...

Answer (score 3):

Multiple inheritance and multiple-level inheritance are not the same. I understand the question is related to the latter.

Let me show my workaround for the problem:

> parent-template.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Your Title</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">
    {% block head %}{% endblock %}
</head>

<body>
    {% block nav %}{% endblock %}
    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
</body>

</html>
```

> child-template.html

```
{% extends 'parent-template.html' %}

{% block nav %}
<header>
    <div>
        <nav>
            ...
            [navbar html code]
            ...
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
{% endblock %}
```

> login.html (where I don't need navbar)

```
{% extends 'parent-template.html' %}

{% block body %}
<header>
    ...
    [header html code]
    ...
</header>
<main>
    ...
    [main html code]
    ...
</main>
{% endblock %}
```

> home.html (where I need navbar)

```
{% extends 'child-template.html' %}

{% block body %}
<main>
    ...
    [main html code]
    ...
</main>
{% endblock %}
```

Both login.html and home.html uses all the data from parent-template, but only home.html uses data from child-template (the navbar).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following way to combine different contents into a single layout.html for various layout designs:

```
{% if instance == 'type1' %}

{% elif instance == 'type2' %}

{% else %}

{% endif %}
```

...and call:

```
render_template('layout', instance='%s' % instance)
```

in python code.