# Jinja2: How to use named blocks inside included templates, inside extendable template

Tags: python, inheritance, include, jinja2, extend

I am having the Issue with Jinja2 Extend and Import.

**base_admin.html**

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="outerbody">
        <somehtml code>
        {% include "base_admin_nav.html" %}
        {% include "base_admin_sidebar.html" %}            
        {% include "base_admin_content.html" %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**base_admin_content.html**

```
<div class="innerbody">
    {% block body_content %}
    {% endblock %}
</div>
```

**admin.html**

```
{% extends 'base_admin.html' %}
{% block body_content %}
    <div>BodyContent</div>
{% endblock %}
```

The code inside body_content is not passed to base_admin_content.html. Any workarounds?

*Note*

> This is not duplicate of this one
>   [jinja2: blocks in included files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13050009/jinja2-blocks-in-included-files)..
>   The include is done in different files here
>
> Defining `{% macro admin_content() %}` insdide `base_admin_content.html` and importing it inside `base_admin.html` using

```
{% from "base_admin_content.html" import admin_content with context %}
        {{ admin_content() }}.
```

> also has no effect.

Comment: What's Jinja2 version are you using?

Comment: Jinja 2.7.1 is the one installed

Answer (score 9):

## Edited - to reflect changes in original question

Ok, now that I know you definitely need the includes, here's how I would do it: instead of including the `base_admin_content.html` file, you should include the `admin.html` file directly into `base_admin.html`. The `admin.html` file will extend `base_admin_content.html` and everything should work just fine:

**base_admin.html**

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="outerbody">
        <somehtml code>
        {% include 'admin.html' %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**admin.html**

```
{% extends 'base_admin_content.html' %}
{% block body_content %}
    <div>BodyContent</div>
{% endblock %}
```

---

**base_admin_content.html**

```
{% block innerbody %}
<div class="innerbody">
    {% block body_content %}
    {% endblock %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

---

### Why does this work but your original code does not?

In your `base_admin.html` file you have

```
{% include 'base_admin_content.html' %}
```

Where we have **no reference to admin.html**, which is why nothing from the **admin.html** file shows up!. Therefore, we should do this:

```
{% include 'admin.html' %}
```

Because that does contain a reference to **base_admin_content** in the extends line:

```
{% extends 'base_admin_content.html' %}
```

Hopefully that makes sense...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Sorry I oversimplified the code.. now added the Edit. There are also many files I needed to include. I can't use the extend like that..

Comment: Please see the ticket also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976651/multiple-level-template-inheritance-in-jinja2

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean now - I've changed my answer to fit a bit closer to what you are asking for. In short - you should include `admin.html` not `base_admin_content.html`

Comment: this answer is weird because it missed the point of OP's template structure. Why would you  `include admin.html` in `base_admin.html`?  Is inverted. So youhave base_admin.html as general structure, admin.html as specific customizations, and `base_admin_content` as partial of the  base_admin page.

Answer (score 0):

You could inherit from base_admin and base_admin_content separately:

base_admin.html:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="outerbody">
        ...
        {% block admin_content %}
            {% include "default_admin_content.html" %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

base_admin_content.html: (unchanged)

```
<div class="innerbody">
    {% block body_content %}{% endblock %}
</div>
```

admin.html:

```
{% extends 'base_admin.html' %}

...
{% block admin_content %}
    {% include "admin_content.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

admin_content.html:

```
{% extends 'base_admin_content.html' %}

{% block body_content %}
    <div>BodyContent</div>
{% endblock %}
```

This way base_admin doesn't need to know about base_admin_content's blocks,
it's flexible and simple.