# get content from parent block in jinja2

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I need to get content from particular block in Jinja2 by console script. For example

```
//global template
{% block target %}
    <some_content_from_top>
{% endblock %}

//parent template
{% extends 'top.html' %}
{% block target %}
    <some_content_from_parent>
{% endblock %}

//child template
{% extends 'parent.html' %}
{% block target %}
    <some_content>
{% endblock %}
```

I can use something like that to get content from this block in particular template without inheritanse

```
template_source = self.env.loader.get_source(self.env, template_path)[0]
parsed_content = self.env.parse(template_source).body
# do something with blck content
```

But how I can get content from all parent templates.Of course I can get parent template name from Extends block and do the same manipulations over and over again tiil I get top-level template without Extends block. But maybe there are more efficient way?

Answer (score 11):

You can use [Jinja2's `super` function](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#super-blocks) to include content from a block in a parent template.

`top.html`

```
{% block target %}
  <some_content_from_top>
{% endblock %}
```

`parent.html`

```
{% extends 'top.html' %}
{% block target %}
  <some_content_from_parent>
  {{ super() }}
{% endblock %}
```

`child.html`

```
{% extends 'parent.html' %}
{% block target %}
  {{ super() }}
  <some_content>
{% endblock %}
```

This will result in:

```
<some_content_from_parent>
<some_content_from_top>
<some_content>
```

Comment: I'm sorry that I missed some important staff in my question. Update question