# Python Flask Jinja - extend/render template when extend a template

Tags: templates, inheritance, flask, jinja2

Let's say we have the layout template "layout.html" where `content` block is defined.

```
<html> {% block content %} {% endblock %} </html>
```

Then, we create another template "somePage.html" which extends this layout.

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
    {% block content %}
        <div> Anything </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

My need is to have `Anything` to **extend** another template, again. E.g.

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
    {% block content %}
        <div> {% extends "anotherTemplate.html" %}</div>
    {% endblock %}
```

Though when doing this, I get the error saying

> TemplateAssertionError: cannot use extend from a non top-level scope

How can I get around this? If you experience similar cases before, please share. Thank you!

Comment: Just see whether it works...add `content block` inside inner extends...

Comment: That will change the template relationship of the current pages. Not possible @SurajPalwe

Comment: You should really look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976651/multiple-level-template-inheritance-in-jinja2

Comment: did you find the answer to this because i need to work around this problem as well

Answer (score 1):

If you change the code to this:

```html
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {{ super() }}
    <div>More html</div>
{% endblock %}
```

You will get the following html:

```html
<div>More html</div>
<div> Anything </div>
```